# Azure multi-tenant application token issueing error

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, multi-tenant, adal

I am trying to create a multi-tenant openidconnect based application using instructions from azure-sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-multitenant-openidconnect

```
AADSTS50000: There was an error issuing a token. 
AADSTS65005: The application needs access to a service that your organization EXTERNALTENANT has not subscribed to. 
Please contact your Administrator to review the configuration of your service subscriptions.
```

I am the admin, where should I update the configuration for this? 
Is it possible to avoid this error with a consent prompt? Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the the tenant which account you were trying login belongs to has no subscription for the resource/permission you have config on the Azure portal.

For example, if you register a application which request the Office 365 SharePoint Online like figure below. However others who trying to sign the application without the subscription to Office 365, then the users would get the error message above.
[image]

To fix this issue, please ensure the customers have the sufficent subscription for the permission you have granted to the application.